# How to rewrite this code block using CFSCRIPT?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am using ColdFusion 8.

I am trying to write this code block in CFSCRIPT, but can't quite get it.

```
<cfloop query="Q">
    <cfscript>
        // CREATE NEW LINE
        NewLine = "";
    NewLine = NewLine & Q.product_url;
    </cfscript>
    <cffile action="append" file="#ThisFile#" output="#NewLine#">
</cfloop>
```

Here is the CFSCRIPT

```
// LOOP THROUGH QUERY RESULTS
for (i = 1; i lte Q.RecordCount; i=i+1) {
    // CREATE NEW LINE
    NewLine = "";
    NewLine = NewLine & Q.product_url[i];
    // READ THE FILE
    File = fileOpen(ThisFile, "read");
    // WRITE NEW LINE TO FILE
    fileWriteLine(File, "#NewLine#");
    fileWrite(ThisFile, File);
    fileClose(File);
}
```

I know I am supposed to open the file, modify it, then close the file. I think I need to do that with each new line added.

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed:

```
<cfscript>
    myFile = fileOpen(ThisFile, "append");

    for (i = 1; i lte Q.RecordCount; i=i+1) {
        NewLine = "";
        NewLine = NewLine & Q.product_url[i];

        fileWriteLine(myFile, "#NewLine#");
    }

    fileClose(myFile);
</cfscript>
```

Issues addressed:

1. You don't open and close the file each line; you a) open file, b) write 1-x lines, then c) close the file (alternately, you can write it all at once with `fileWrite()` )
2. You don't need both fileWriteLine and fileWrite, fileWriteLine is for line-by-line writing, while fileWrite is for writing and entire set of data in one shot.

I also changed the "write" to "append", in case the file you're writing to doesn't exist upon the first execution--obviously, if you can guarantee your destination file exists, you can replace "append" with "write". Keep in mind that changing this will also grow your file over time; it may not be what you want, so switch it back to "write" if this is the case.

Although I can't be certain without seeing your exact error, I have a hunch it was `FileWrite()` line that was the culprit.

Comment: Wow! That's as easy as it should be. I got my example directly from Adobe and didn't quite understand why it would need to be that verbose.  Shawn, when I get back to work on Monday, I'll post the link to Adobe where I got the example (which I made into my version).  Thanks so much!!!